# Load common.sass style on top of a Reacts components

Tags: sass, reactjs, webpack

I'm building a react application with SASS for the styles and serving it with webpack-dev-server, a couple of components and some extract of the structure look like that:

```
├── App.js
├── components
│   ├── Layout.jsx
│   ├── Layout.scss
│   ├── header
│   ├── pages
│   └── footer
└── css
    ├── _vendors.scss
    ├── _variables.scss
    ├── _mixins.scss
    └── utils.scss
```

Inside `main.scss`, I have all the `@imports`, also inside the vendors I have the imports in node_modules dependencies, etc...
Per each component in react have his own scss file.
But, I want the main.scss loaded in the Layout.jsx and use the mixins or imports or placeholder classes inside the scss file per component.

I was trying playing with `css-loader` and `style-loader` with includePath's and nothing successful.

It's this possible? It's related on the -loaders of webpack?
ps: Isn't viable have an .html file, this is a library of components.

Answer (score 0):

A good way I found to keep track of styles for various react components is to have a style file for each corresponding component. So `Header.react.jsx` would have a corresponding `Header.sass`. Then you just include the style file on top of the react component, like so (using the ES6 syntax):

```
import './Header.sass';
```

For this to work with webpack, you need the appropriate loaders:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.sass/,
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer!sass'
    }
]
```

This is nice for development, because the styles are loaded in javascript and get updated automatically on any change if you're using the hot loader, but in production, you'd want to separate out the css file with all the styles. You can do this with a separate webpack config file for production, which can look something like this:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css', { allChunks: false })
],
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.scss/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
            'style-loader',
            'css!autoprefixer!sass'
        )
    }
]
```

When doing things this way, it's good to include a sass config file and a mixin file, for the variables or mixins you use globally (with the regular sass `@import`). It's important not to define any actual styles in the files you import, since the styles would be included into all files you include it in, resulting in loads of duplication.

This is good for component libraries (as you put it), since webpack will only include the react components you use in your application, and in turn, it will only pull in the sass files you use.

I found this approach very handy, and used it in a smaller application [here](https://github.com/pavlin-policar/SocialNetwork-Client). Take a look if I haven't explained it well enough.

Comment: As far as I know, If you use ExtractTextPlugin, you'r creating a `bundle.css` with all of your required styles in the .jsx. In case of using `allChunks: false` you only create style per each component right?

Comment: Actually, the `allChunks: false` isn't required here. I was playing around with the option a while ago and I must have forgrotten to remove it. If you use the ExtractTextPlugin, you create a separate css file yes, that's what you'd would typically want to do in a production environment for easier caching. But during development, you'd want the live updates, so there's no need to extract it into a separate file.

Comment: But what I want is not having a extracted css file, and adding it into the .html, because I don't have any index.html.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What you do is write the react components, and their corresponding stylesheets and include those in the react component. You can do whatever with them. In the event you wish to use one of said components, all you would have to do is include the component with `require <component>;` or `include <component> from ...` and you would get the stylesheet for that component, and that component alone with that single import. I understand you have no entry point, but if you're writing a library of components, you probably want the usage of said components to be simple as well.

Comment: Yes, and using some mixins/variables/extra classes that are declared on a main.scss, inside the scss the component itself. Do you get it?

Comment: Yes I understand. In that case, just make sure whoever uses your library includes the main.scss file somewhere in the application, probably the entry.js. I fail to see how that's a problem. The benefit of my approach is that if the user of your library uses only one component, they don't get the css of all the components, just the ones they decide to use.

Comment: Add the main in each component is ugly, I need to be sure that this main have only mixins, not css declarations...